# .Net reflection to get nested property with custom attribute

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I want to know the best way to get the prop info and value using reflection for a nested class by its custom attribute name.
With below code I can get the prop info via recursion. But is there a better way or using LINQ. Note that I do not want to hard code the class type as similar to other solution

I also want to get the property value by custom attribute

e.g var propValue = ?????

```
 public class PlanetRoot

    {

        public void GetNeighborMoon()

        {

            Planet planet = new Planet();

            Product product = new Product();

            Neighbor neighbor = new Neighbor();

            neighbor.Moons = 10;

            neighbor.RingColor = "Red";

            product.Neighbors = new List<Neighbor>();

            product.Neighbors.Add(neighbor);

            planet.Product = product;



            //1. Get the RingColor property info of neighbor with attribute MyDBField(Name = "NeighborRing") . Is there a better way

            PropertyInfo propInfo = null;
            DoRecursiveGetProperty(planet.GetType(), "NeighborRing", out propInfo );



            //2. Get the RingColor property value of neighbor with attribute MyDBField(Name = "NeighborRing")

            //var propValue = GetPropertyValue(????);

        }

    }



    private static PropertyInfo DoRecursiveGetProperty(Type type, string attribName, out PropertyInfo propInfo)

    {

        PropertyInfo[] pi = type.GetProperties();

        propInfo= null;

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi)

        {

            var dbFieldAttribute = (MyDBFieldAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(MyDBFieldAttribute));

            if (dbFieldAttribute != null && attribName.ToUpper() == dbFieldAttribute.Name.ToUpper())

            {

                propInfo= p;

                //Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + (dbFieldAttribute != null && dbFieldAttribute.Name != null ? dbFieldAttribute.Name : "****"));

                return true;

            }



            if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && !p.PropertyType.IsValueType && !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive

            && p.PropertyType.FullName != "System.String")
                if (propInfo != null) return true;
                else DoRecursiveGetProperty(p.PropertyType, attribName, out propInfo);



        }



        return false;



    }

    public class Planet

    {

        public string PlanetId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Product Product { get; set; }



        [MyDBField(Name="PubDate")]

        public string Publishdate { get; set; }



    }



    public class Product

    {

        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public List<Neighbor> Neighbors { get; set; }



    }



    public class Neighbor

    {

        [MyDBField(Name = "NeighborRing")]

        public string RingColor { get; set; }

        public int Moons { get; set; }

    }



    public class MyDBFieldAttribute : System.Attribute

    {

        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Your point 2 seems unclear - the attribute "NeighborRing" applies to every instance of `Neighbor` so every member of the `Neighbors` list has that attribute - which value do you want? IOTW, you already know `Planet.Product.Neighbors[].RingColor` is the property in question - why do you need to use Reflection?

Comment: While I agree with @NetMage, if you just want a property's value while holding a PropertyInfo instance and the object you want the property of, you can just use PropertyInfo.GetValue: `object propValue = propInfo.GetValue(planet);` under your line with `2.`.

Comment: Do you want to iterate through the properties of a class, and then the properties of each property value, and so forth, and then return just a single `PropertyInfo`? That's a little confusing. What if that hierarchy contains more than one property with the attribute? (Sorry, I changed my comment after you replied to it. I had initially pointed out that there were no nested classes.)

Comment: @ScottHannen By nested classes, it is meant classes that contain members that are instances of other classes, e.g. `Product` is the type of a member of `Planet`, and hence nested.

Comment: @SeanSkelly Perhaps the issue is there is no object reference since the `PropertyInfo` references a nested member of the original class and following that trail isn't obvious?

Comment: @NetMage Yes, you're right.  My comment won't work.  Perhaps the DoRecursiveGetProperty should do this work, instead of returning the PropertyInfo, since it will have the object reference in hand anyway.  Which is basically your answer.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the value for a nested member that might be in a collection, you need to iterate the collections, and track the current object.

Assuming you don't need the resulting `PropInfo` for other reasons, just try to get the value:

```
private static bool TryRecursiveGetValueWithMyDBFieldName(object startObject, string attribName, out object propValue) {
    PropertyInfo[] pi = startObject.GetType().GetProperties();

    foreach (PropertyInfo p in pi) {
        var dbFieldAttribute = (MyDBFieldAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(p, typeof(MyDBFieldAttribute));
        if (dbFieldAttribute != null && dbFieldAttribute.Name.Equals(attribName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)) {
            //Console.WriteLine(p.Name + " : " + (dbFieldAttribute != null && dbFieldAttribute.Name != null ? dbFieldAttribute.Name : "****"));
            propValue = p.GetValue(startObject);
            return true;
        }

        if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && !p.PropertyType.IsValueType && !p.PropertyType.IsPrimitive &&
            !p.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.")) {
            var tryObject = p.GetValue(startObject);
            if (tryObject != null && TryRecursiveGetValueWithMyDBFieldName(tryObject, attribName, out propValue))
                return true;
        }

        if (p.PropertyType.IsClass && p.GetValue(startObject) is IEnumerable ip) {
            foreach (var obj in ip) {
                if (obj != null && TryRecursiveGetValueWithMyDBFieldName(obj, attribName, out propValue))
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    propValue = default;
    return false;
}
```

To use it, call with the initial object:

```
var foundAttrib = TryRecursiveGetValueWithMyDBFieldName(planet, "NeighborRing", out var propValue);
```

NOTE: This will return the value of the first object with a matching attribute, as e.g. every member of the `List<Neighbor>` member will have the `MyDBField` attribute with the `Name` property of `NeighborRing`.

Comment: I am using .Net 4.7 and when I call 
var foundAttrib = TryRecursiveGetValueWithMyDBFieldName(planet, "NeighborRing", out var propValue);
I get a object reference null exception on line 
PropertyInfo[] pi = startObject.GetType().GetProperties();

I see that startObject is null when debugging

Comment: @SA. I assume you aren't testing with your sample code - I added some `null` checks for the recursive calls when property values or collection elements are `null` for some reason.

Comment: yes you are right. I was not testing with the sample code. I was using a many level nested object with some property values not set. I added 
if(startObject != null) 
and then it works fine. Thank you

Comment: @SA. My edited answer prevents recursing when the value is null so you don't make an extra method call - unless your starting call might be with a `null` reference.